# Unable to export last updated multiple line text field into excel

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, multiline-text-field

I'm new to sp. I created a simple wf in sp designer to set field value of multiple line into a single line text field but this turns out to be blank as not always this particular field is updated but other fields I'm the list are updated.

I saw one of your old post where you have achieved this. Can you help me to SEtup the condition to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have enabled the **`Append Changes To Existing Text`** for the Multiline column.

[image]

> **Note:** The Multiline column with **Append Changes** will save each new change
>   as a version (where **versioning** is a mandatory prerequisite to
>   enable **Append Changes**). In this case, the Multiline column
>   value of the current version is **blank**! so it shows blank!

**Solution**,

- Set **`Append Changes To Existing Text`** to **NO**!!

Comment: Thank Qussas. Is there a way to achieve this with the append option on ?. I have on the other hand tried disabling the append option and then adding a new field to capture previous value everytime the field is updated. Have inserted a condition not to copy text when it is not updated when someone field in the form is updated.

Comment: I mean to say, I have achieved this with three fields named  description, description latest with append option on and description previous with the same property as the field description. The description previous checks with value in description and if they are different the description latest is set to description. This also then sets description previous to the value in description.

Comment: @Charles Great!, it's alternative solution with workflow in case you don't need to disable *Append Changes To Existing Text* on the main field, So the above answer explained the correct root cause and the OOTB solution! so please don't forget to set it as an answer in case it helped and guide you to the correct way!

Comment: Hi @Charles I have noticed that you have added the comments as a new answer! To mark the answer as accepted, you can click on the **True** sign beside the answer!